# BIM360 folder permissions and users under each company?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

1. I am following the tutorials about [Retrieve a User’s Folder Permissions](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/document-management/retrieve-user-permissions/)
2. After the first step in the tutorial, I Retrieved Folder Permissions including users and companies, but then I can not find any api for checking what are the users under each specific company.

**Scenario for this request:**

I have a BIM360 Documents assigned to couples users and some companies. With [this endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/document-management-projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-permissions-GET/) I can retrieves the users list that can access this documents as well as company list that can access this documents.

**Problem:**
There are users assigned to each company, I can not know what are the users under each company.I didn't find any endpoint for check sub-users(who can access to the BIM360 Documents) under each company.

Comment: That is too bad, thanks!
Do you know if there is endpoint for retrieving all of the BIM360 projects that a user can access?

Comment: My bad! I missed this endpoint Search Users. It allows you to set filter company_name which can tell all the users which under this specific company https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/users-search-GET/